# How to do this the right way? Declaring static object in function

Tags: c++, object, global

The way I did it works, but feels like unbelievably bad programming.

```
void draw_display() 
{
    static DISPLAY mydisplay = DISPLAY(parameters);
    mydisplay.set_orientation(0);

    do something with mydisplay... 
}
```

So the the `draw_display` function is called by a interrupt from a microcontroller.
In my ideal world, I would declare the `mydisplay` object somewhere global, setup the orientation and just use the global object in the function.

What would be the right c++ way to do this?

This is more of a "doing it the right way" and learn from it question.

Comment: I understand you need the peformance and only want to do the initialization once. I am usually not in favor of global variables (big projects/unit testability). But if this is an interrupt handler I would move the initialization of DISPLAY out of the function and do it once at strartup of your code. This way your first handling of the interrupt might be too slow (since mydisplay would be initialized at first call).

Comment: You may read about "singleton pattern" in C++.

Comment: Are you asking how to call `set_orientation` only once?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, my goal would be to call set_orientation only once. Also, it feels kind of wrong to initialize the object as static inside the function.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes, you are absolutely right. So in this case you would tend towards globally declaring the object? Then i could move the set_orientation to main.

Comment: No substitue for testing in the real world :) Just give it a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my goal would be to call set_orientation only once.

Then you can use an immediately-invoked lambda:

```
static DISPLAY mydisplay = []{
{
    DISPLAY ret(parameters);
    ret.set_orientation(0);
    return ret;
}();
```

Comment: That seems to be a nice alternative to a global object. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that the DISPLAY class has a proper constructor with the required parameters. You should also make sure that it has a destructor if necessary.

Initialize mydisplay outside the draw_display function. This ensures that you don't create a new DISPLAY object every time the function is called. You can use a constructor or initialization function to set up the object initially.

```
class DISPLAY {
    public:
        DISPLAY(parameters) {
            // Constructor implementation with parameters
        }
    
        ~DISPLAY() {
            // Destructor implementation if necessary
        }
    
        void set_orientation(int orientation) {
            // Implementation of set_orientation
        }
    
        // Other member functions and data members
   };
    
    // Initialize mydisplay outside of draw_display
    static DISPLAY mydisplay(parameters);
    
    void draw_display() {
        mydisplay.set_orientation(0);
    
        // Do something with mydisplay...
    }
```

Comment: OP wants the `set_orientation` call at the "start". Put it in the ctor at least.